# Play sound from URI in c#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, audio, stream, soundcloud

Is there any way I can play audio in my c#.NET application by using a soundcloud stream URI? I found a method to do this with windows 8 phones:

`new AudioTrack(new Uri("[your soundcloud uri]", UriKind.Absolute), "[Track Name]", "[Artist]", "[Album]", null)`

But I can't find a method to do this in desktop .NET framework. Could someone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SoundCloud uses mp3 as streaming format, you may use WMPLib. First you need to add reference of it (Project -> References -> Add Reference -> COM -> Windows Media Player)

```
var wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.URL = "http://somewebsite.com/somedir/somefile.mp3";
wplayer.controls.play();
```

But on computers without Windows Media Player (Like Windows N, KN), you may need third-party libraries to play soundcloud streams. For example, [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

ps: btw, the play of WMPLib is async, so you need to register to StateChange event to know whether the music is ended. See the MSDN Article.

Reference: [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)